# Is Shadowing Lemma specific to hyperbolic dynamical systems?

Tags: dynamical-systems, solution-verification, alternative-proof, uniform-continuity, hyperbolic-geometry

In a *hyperbolic dynamical* system, the *Shadowing lemma* states that every epsilon-pseudo-orbit is uniquely delta-shadowed by some orbit. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowing_lemma

It  is not clear to me why this is *specific* to hyperbolic dynamical systems. What about the following general proof for (uniform) continuous functions.

Dynamical system $f:X\to X$ continuous, s.th. $d(f(x),f(y))<C\cdot d(x,y)$.
Let $(x_n)$ be a epsilon-pseudo-orbit, i.e. $d(f(x_n),x_{n+1})<\epsilon$. Let's estimate $d(f^n(x_0),x_n)$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$: We have

- $d(f(x_0),x_1)<\epsilon$ as demanded per premise
- $d(f^2(x_0),x_2) \overset{\Delta\text{ inequality}}{\leq} \underbrace{d(f^2(x_0),f(x_1))}_{<C \cdot \underbrace{d(f(x_0),x_1)}_{<\epsilon}}+ \underbrace{d(f(x_1),x_2) }_{<\epsilon} \leq (C+1)\epsilon$
- $d(f^3(x_0),x_3)\overset{\Delta\text{ inequality}}{\leq} \underbrace{d(f^3(x_0),f(x_2))}_{<C\cdot \underbrace{ d(f^2(x_0),x_2)}_{\leq (C+1)\epsilon}}+  \underbrace{d(f(x_2),x_3)}_{<\epsilon} \leq (C^2+C+1)\epsilon$
- per induction ...
- $d(f^n(x_0),x_n) \leq (C^{n-1}+ \dots+1)\epsilon=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C^k \cdot\epsilon=\frac{1-C^n}{1-C}\epsilon \leq \delta$.

Thus, we find that the point $x_0$ induces a shadow orbit per $y_n:=f^n(x_0)$, that is arbitrary close ($\delta$ close) if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.

**Question** What is the error in this proof, why do you expend such an effort to proof the shadowing lemma for hyperbolic dynamical systems if it is true in such a wide sense?

**Edit** Given $\delta>0$, define $\epsilon(N) :=\underbrace{ \min_{n=0}^N \left( \frac{1-C}{1-C^n}\right) }_{=  \frac{1-C}{1-C^N} }   \cdot \delta$ .
The limit for $N\to\infty$ (i.e. shadowing for all $n$ which is infinite orbits) exists for $C<1$ and is $1-C$ s.th. we choose $\epsilon:=(1-C)\delta$ independend of $N$. (for $C=1$ the geometric series expression is wrong but the limit does not exist either)

Comment: @LutzLehmann : In how far is the periodic theorem related or relevant in this context? I think it's basically a corollary of the shadowing lemma?

Comment: Thanks for appending, So what did I miss in the full theorem? I definitely must have missed something important.
Is the following correct?: A connected Riemannian  manifold     induces a metric space (by infimum of length of curves between points on manifold). So we can apply the results obtained by the above mentioned proof from metric spaces to Riemannian manifolds (only those are regarded here, sorry for  not mentioning it)

Comment: I deleted my comments because I had the impression that the lemma was about periodic orbits or cycles. As that is not the case, the argument reduces to that in the answer of Lee Mosher, the pseudo-orbit can run away from the exact orbit, especially in the infinite case.

Comment: See http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hyperbolic_dynamics for a coherent presentation of all the entities mentioned in the question.

Comment: especially or only in the infinite case?
Is that the only point in which the shadowing lemma comes into play? So there is absolutely no need to use the shadowing lemma for finite orbits because this is evident in metric spaces? Can you confirm or correct my question about metric induces by Riemannian manifold (comment above)?

Comment: And is the assumption of Lipschitz continuity correct in the case of C^1 diffeomorphisms on a smooth manifold? Then for $C<1$ we  obtain this result without shadowing lemma. So what is it for then after all?

Comment: No, this assumption does not hold. Hyperbolic means that there are expanding directions and contracting directions around each point, the Lipschitz constant will be larger than $1$ in every case.

Comment: is the assumption of Lipschitz continuity correct in the case of C^1 diffeomorphisms on a smooth and compact Riemannian manifold (as metric space)? (not necessarily <1)

Comment: Yes, a $C^1$ function on a compact manifold has a bounded derivative and thus a Lipschitz constant.

Comment: Note also that the lemma states that the shadow sequence reaches forward and backward, $d(x_n,y_n)<δ$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. A map that is contracting forward is expanding backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are, basically, errors of logic.

The shadowing lemma says that for any $\delta > 0$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\epsilon$-pseudo-orbit $(x_n)$ there exists a true orbit $(y_n)$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) < \delta$.

So the outer ring of the logic of the proof should be: given $\delta>0$, produce $\epsilon>0$ as a function of $\delta$ independent of $n$. You seem to instead have produced $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ depending on $n$.

Also, in the inner ring of logic, given an $\epsilon$ pseudo-orbit $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ you must produce a true orbit $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ and then prove that $d(x_n,y_n) < \delta$ for all $n$. You seem to have instead have proved $d(f^n(x_0),x_n) < \delta$, which is quite beside the point (and, again, using a $\delta$ which depends on $n$ and on $\epsilon$, which is quite beside the point of the outer ring of logic).

If you'd like to see how you can critique your own proof, here's a suggestion. Consider the identity function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. It's an isometry, $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$ so it satisfies your hypothesis with $C=2$. Every orbit of $f$ is just a single point. Here's an unshadowable $\epsilon$-pseudo-orbit:
$$x_n = n \, \epsilon \, / \, 2
$$
What does your proof do when confronted with this example?

Comment: concerning _outer logic_: We can write $\epsilon$ as a function of $\delta$. The dependence on $n$ can be removed by taking the $\max$. So basically, do you mean it is  the fact that the theorem is true for infinite orbits? Is this the only fact?
concerning _inner logic_: The true orbit is defined $y_n:=f^n(x_0)$, i.e.  simply stating that  $x_0$ induces the shadow-orbit.

Comment: Yes, the shadowing theorem is a theorem about infinite pseudo-orbits. It is sometimes applied to periodic infinite pseudo-orbits, i.e. to pseudo-orbits $(x_n)$ for which there exists an integer $p \ge 1$ such that $x_n = x_{n+p}$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: So we can simply say that the whole point of the shadowing theorem is to demonstrate the case of infinite orbits whereby the finite case can be proven simply without all the assumptions of hyperbolicity. It's disappointing to expend an effort for this little upgrade

Comment: Perhaps... except for the fact that the finite version is useless whereas the infinite version has many powerful applications.

Comment: ok, thank you. Can you provide a powerful application in the context of dynamical systems (where $C>1$ s.th my proof does not work)?  
Question: Do you refer to two-sided infinite orbits $(x_n),\; n\in\mathbb Z$ or only forward infinite orbits?
Btw: I edited my initial question and precised the definition of the chosen pseudo-orbit .

Comment: One application is density of periodic orbits in a basic set of a hyperbolic dynamical system. See for example my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95477/tangled-knot-function/95481#95481) over on MathOverflow, in which I allude to that density in the flow case.